# Elastic search filtered query, query part being ignored?

Tags: filter, dsl, elasticsearch

I'm building up the following search in code, the idea being that it filters down the set of matches then queries this so I can add score based on certain fields. For some reason the filter part works but whatever I put in the query (i.e. in the below I have no index sdfsdfsdf) it still returns anything matching the filter.

Is the syntax wrong?

```
 {  
       "query":{  
          "filtered":{  
             "query":{  
                "bool":{  
                   "must":{  
                      "match":{  
                         "sdfsdfsdf":{  
                            "query":"4",
                            "boost":2.0
                         }
                      }
                   }
                },
                "filter":{  
                   "bool":{  
                      "must":[  
                         {  
                            "terms":{  
                               "_id":[  
                                  "55f93ead5df34f1900abc20b",
                                  "55f8ab0226ec4bb216d7c938",
                                  "55dc4e949dcf833308c63d6b"
                               ]
                            }
                         },
                         {  
                            "range":{  
                               "published_date":{  
                                  "lte":"now"
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      ],
                      "must_not":{  
                         "terms":{  
                            "_id":[  
                               "55f0a799acccc28204a5058c"
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: If I run the query part on its own it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filter` is not at the right level. It should not be inside `query` but at the same level as `query` like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {          <--- query and filter at the same level
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "sdfsdfsdf": {
                "query": "4",
                "boost": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {         <--- query and filter at the same level
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": [
                  "55f93ead5df34f1900abc20b",
                  "55f8ab0226ec4bb216d7c938",
                  "55dc4e949dcf833308c63d6b"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "published_date": {
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": {
            "terms": {
              "_id": [
                "55f0a799acccc28204a5058c"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `sdfsdfsdf` with your existing field name in your type, e.g. `title`, otherwise I think it will fallback to match_all query.

```
"match":{  
        "title":{  
              "query": "some text here",
              "boost":2.0
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but even when I use the real field name "product_id" with a query of "2" it is returning records that have a product_id that is not 2